# How to grant Full Access and Send on Behalf permissions in Exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013

We have migrated from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013.

We have multiple shared mailboxes and we have always granted users `Full Access` and `Send on Behalf` permission so that if a shared mailbox receives an e-mail and a user replies it appears to come from `Doe, John On Behalf Of Sales`.

In ECP in Exchange 2013 there is only `Full Access` and `Send As` permissions in the online control panel. How do I grant `Full Access` and `Send On Behalf`?

#### Edit: I don't want "Send As". I want "Send on Behalf".

I do not want `Send As`. I do *not* want the e-mails to look as if they were sent by the shared mailbox. I want the Exchange 2010 behavior so that when an employee replies to an e-mail sent to a shared mailbox the recipient sees `Doe, John On Behalf Of Sales`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Powershell to configure, `Send on Behalf`, `Send as`, `Full Mailbox Access`.

Below are examples.

- **Send on Behalf**

  This will grant Charles permissions to `send on behalf` of Gert.

  ```
  Set-Mailbox gert.mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo charles.surname
  ```
- **Send As**

  This will grant Charles permissions to `send as` Gert.

  ```
  Add-ADPermission gert.mailbox -ExtendedRights Send-As -user charles.surname
  ```
- **Full Mailbox Access**

  This will grant Charles `full access` to Gert's mailbox.

  Add-MailboxPermission -Identity gert.mailbox -User charles.surname

## Update: Microsoft Example

Here is a way from Microsoft:
(Exchange 2016: [*Create a shared mailbox*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150570). Archived [here](https://archive.is/8tIx2).)

**Use the Shell to create a shared mailbox**

This example creates the shared mailbox `Sales Department` and grants `Full Access` and `Send on Behalf` permissions for the security group `MarketingSG`. Users who are members of the security group will be granted the permissions to the mailbox.

**Note:**
This example assumes that you’ve already created the security group `MarketingSG` and that security group is mail-enabled. See *Manage mail-enabled security groups*.

```
New-Mailbox -Shared -Name "Sales Department" -DisplayName "Sales Department" -Alias Sales |
    Set-Mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo MarketingSG |
    Add-MailboxPermission -User MarketingSG -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Send on behalf` permissions with PowerShell / EMS if it is not available in ECP:

`Set-Mailbox mailbox.domain -GrantSendOnBehalfTo userIdentity`

But actually I am not sure if this is possible with shared mailboxes. Is there any special reason why you don't want to use `Send As`?

Regards

**EDIT:** I just found that it is not possible to set `Send on behalf` for shared mailboxes in the Exchange 2013 online help: [Manage Permissions for Recipients - Exchange Online Help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919240%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

**EDIT2:** In another Microsoft document, you'll find the sentence:

> You can’t use the EAC to grant `Send on Behalf` permissions, you must use
>   `Set-Mailbox` cmdlet with the `GrantSendonBehalf` parameter.

[Create a shared Mailbox - Exchange 2013 Help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150570%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

So, maybe you should just give a try to the EMS trick?

Comment: `EDIT: I just found that it is not possible to set "Send on behalf" for shared mailboxes in the Exchange 2013 online help: Manage Permissions for Recipients - Exchange Online Help`. Then why do the existing continue to work?

Comment: See my second edit above, there are two different articles from Microsoft, one says "impossible", the other says "only with EMS".

Answer (score 0):

GrantSendOnBehalfTo and Full Access Rights for bulk AD Users from CSV file
This script generates a brief of all current users have access to send on behalf then based on the template CSV file will import and grant Full Mailbox Access and send on behalf access to the AD users. 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/Grant-SendOnBehalf-and-175fee83

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue using client credentials grant flow to authenticate connections where none of the already mentioned commands worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558889/azure-ad-service-principal-client-credentials-grant-authenticate-failed-accessin

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-imap-and-pop-connections

We used this command to give our application's service principal access to one mailbox:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "john.smith@contoso.com" -User <SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps

However when trying to use the commands below we encountered errors:

```
Set-Mailbox gert.mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo charles.surname

Add-ADPermission gert.mailbox -ExtendedRights Send-As -user charles.surname
```

`Set-Mailbox` could not find the service principal object and `Add-ADPermission` is not available in Exchange Online.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-adpermission?view=exchange-ps

[image]

We could however solve it with:

```
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "john.smith@contoso.com" -Trustee <SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights SendAs
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-recipientpermission?view=exchange-ps